# How can I split in half a double-page scanned PDF in a single pass?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a scanned course and it has two pages, consecutive are showing as one page, how can I automatically split all the pages in one pass. Usually this is done by cropping odd and even pages and then merge them back together but this could take very much?

How can I split pages on scanned PDF in a single pass?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There's an excellent, free and open source tool called [Briss](https://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/?source=typ_redirect). It is very simple, user friendly and effective. It works on multiple operating systems through Java.

Load your PDF into the app. The app will group similar pages together and lay them on top of each other. Draw rectangles on top of your pages so that they cover what you want included. It will look like this:

[image]

Even if your PDF has multiple categories of layout within a single document, Briss will handle it. For example, let's say some parts are in portrait and others in landscape. Briss will group them into different categories and let you draw different rectangles on them, and then process it all in a single pass, into a single document. Briss is very good at deciding which pages should be grouped together. It typically takes me less then a minute of manual work to get Briss started. Thus, a document of hundreds or even thousands of pages can be done in a couple of minutes thanks to this brilliant program.

When it looks good, select **Action**, then **Crop PDF**.

Truly a very neat tool.

**Note:** I realize this answer reads like I'm a Briss developer or something, but I'm really not. I just love the tool.

Comment: This tool is amazing, nearly everything I could ask for to deal with messy scans--even scans of documents that inconsistently have two pages together as one image, then just one page, then two again.  Saved me hours.

Comment: I have used Briss and this tool is simply amazoning. I highly recommend this tool for the mentioned use case.

Comment: That name is *chef's kiss*

Comment: One of the best GUI tools I've ever downloaded !

Comment: Installing briss on a Mac is easy when you have homebrew installed: `brew install briss`. Then start with `briss`.

Comment: @Christoph yes, in the MacOS this works fine. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, there is also [briss-2.0](https://github.com/mbaeuerle/Briss-2.0) which is intended to be a GUI update for the original briss mentioned above. It has been in alpha for years, though.

Comment: Last release is May 2012. Seems abandoned.

Comment: @robertspierre as Christoph mentioned above efort goes into briss 2.0 https://github.com/mbaeuerle/Briss-2.0/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 53):

You could use [MuPDF](https://mupdf.com)'s `mutool`:

```
mutool poster -x 2 in.pdf out.pdf
```

Comment: DUDE! This is the best answer hands-down. It was instantaneous to split a document with 24 two-page spreads into 48 pages perfectly!

Comment: Good answer, simple, fast and quality. One comment: my scan results had pages one at right, one at left. The command to split with a vertical cut has been mutool poster -y 2 in.pdf out.pdf

Comment: I used the same thing but split pages horizontally with `mutool poster yx 2 in.pdf out.pdf`. Very useful tool.

Comment: I've installed like 10+ different dependencies and the `make` output still ask me for more C dependencies that I cannot find... would make the project more popular if you publish a binary version in the download page, I just want to split a document, not a contributor of the project.

Comment: @MarianoRuiz - Might it be possible that you mistook me for maintainer of `mupdf`, who I am not? Anyway, there are precompiled binaries for many operating systems, just check your package manager, e.g. `sudo apt-get install mupdf-tools` on ubuntu or `brew install mupdf-tools` on macOS

Comment: Wow, that thing is fast. I was at first thinking that failed since it was about instantaneous on a 300MB PDF.  Nope, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Excellent. Just, too bad the right page comes before the left one with this method (Japanese reading)

Comment: @brahmin -- You could use the `shuffle` operation of [`pdftk`](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk) for that

Answer (score 35):

After looking on some internet answers (it is a question often asked ) I discovered that this can be done easily using the **`Poster`** option from the **`Print`** menu.

**Steps (for Adobe Acrobat XI)**:

1. Choose `Print` from `File` Menu or `Ctrl+P`
2. Select `Printer` as Adobe PDF
3. Select `Poster` tab.
4. Change `Overlap` to `0` inch
5. Adjust the `Tile scale` to your needs, 100%(99%) if the result printed PDF page size is same as the current PDF page size, 75% if the printed pdf page size is half the current pdf. Tinker with "Tile scale" percents if necessary to obtain your desired result. To check the the result printed PDF page size go right of "Adobe PDF" combo-box select `Properties` and change `Adobe PDF Page Size`combo-box if necessary.
6. You can hit `Print` button when the page looks split like you desired, check the dotted line in the guiding preview:

[image]

Here is a print screen for the described settings:

[image]

Comment: Note that this very good method will work only on Windows, as on Mac, it is no longer possible to "print" to PS/PDF using the print dialog (reason: Apple changed something in OSX which suppresses the previously used workflow in Acrobat).

Comment: There is a workaround, but it is definitely not for the faint at heart, and "should not be done at home" (print to a non-connected PostScript printer, and then snitch the spool file, and feed that into Distiller).

Comment: @MaxWyss Could you give more details about the workaround?

Comment: @JairoBochi I don't have a mac to test, but this should help:

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=44&platform=Macintosh

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/creating-pdfs-acrobat-distiller.html

Comment: @JairoBochi: As described, you create a generic PDF printer (in the Printer and Scanner System Preferences), select it, and "print" to that printer. In /var/spool/ you find the spool files, which you can then snitch. You need to be su to access those files. Note: for Windows, it is not necessary, because the AdobePS printer driver still works properly.

Comment: I don't see the dotted line in my preview. How did you get those lines?

Comment: @FangJing Try tune the tile scale

Comment: I wasn't able to create a "generic PDF printer" on Mac OS as you described, but I was able to print to my regular printer and then pause it before anything actually printed. I found a large recently created file in /var/spool/cups and it was my document. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

[Sejda.com](https://www.sejda.com) can [split scanned PDF documents in half](https://www.sejda.com/split-pdf-down-the-middle), down the middle. Works on all desktop platforms.

Here's a short how to:

[image: How to split scanned PDF documents in half with Sejda.com]

If it's a booklet scan and the pages are not in their natural order anymore it can reorder them for you too.

I'm a developer on the project. [Open source](http://sejda.org).

Comment: Behtareen! Best app I have ever used for PDF tasks...

Comment: only one complaint - it does not allow cutting out some borders like Briss

Comment: You can cut out borders in a second pass using the crop tool: https://www.sejda.com/crop-pdf

Comment: Thank you! BTW, for those wondering, this works even without a booklet scan structure, where it's just one page that's A3 that you want to split into A4, with consecutive page numbers.

Comment: Whoa! Seriously impressive. It stacked all of the scans with low transparency, asked me where to 'chop' the left/right sides, and then split them into individual pages. Turned an annoying task into something trivial. I'm bookmarking this site for sure.

Comment: There are limits to this tool to force you to pay. 100pages, 50MB, 3 tasks per day. etc

Comment: Not a good idea to upload your PDFs to some random site. And not necessary for this very simple task.

Answer (score 7):

There are two problem with automating splitting scanned books in a single pass:

- Automation is not always accuracy
- Making a scanned book comfortably read is more than just splitting pages

For everything related with scanned books, I highly recommend using [ScanTailor Advanced](https://github.com/ScanTailor-Advanced/scantailor-advanced). It has features such as:

- Turn skewed pages vertically,
- Select content to reduce the page size,
- Increase/decrease margin (for notetaking, maybe),
- Whiten the result for better reading experience.

[image]

You must export the PDF into images to use this, and recombine the output images back. The processed images may be very small in file size (up to only 6% of the origin), but excellent in quality.

From [its original GitHub repo](https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor):

> Scan Tailor is Free Software (which is more than just freeware). It’s written in C++ with Qt and released under the General Public License version 3. We develop both Windows and GNU/Linux versions.

## Other tips

To complete the task satisfactorily, I recommend you to use [PDF-Xchange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) for extracting images and adding OCR, [i2pdf](https://freeshell.de/%7Eluis/i2pdf/) for merging the outputs. In my experience, you can set the JPG quality to the lowest and it doesn't seem much different, but you have a trade-off between the final output's size and image quality. All programs are free. The whole process takes around 1 hour in background, with occasional checks.

I also have a complete guide to process scanned books, you may want to check it out: [The ultimate guide to process scanned books](http://lyminhnhat.com/resources/productivity/process-scanned-books/?utm_source=SE%3A%20Super%20User&utm_medium=Working%20with%20scanned%20books&utm_campaign=Productivity&utm_term=post%3A%20How%20can%20I%20split%20in%20half%20a%20double-page%20scanned%20PDF%20in%20a%20single%20pass%3F).

FYI: [How to create hierarchical bookmarks on scanned PDF files?](https://superuser.com/a/1263185/301042)

Comment: ScanTailor has been abandoned and is no longer maintained.

Comment: @robertspierre you are right. At first I thought there is still ScanTailor Advanced, but [it's also abandoned as well](https://github.com/4lex4/scantailor-advanced/issues/170). However in the thread there is a link to [a new fork](https://github.com/ScanTailor-Advanced/scantailor-advanced) that is active last week

Answer (score 1):

The free (as in freedom) [pdfarranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger) can do that.

Just select the pages you want to split, right click and select "Split pages":

[image]

[image]