# How can I add an outine to a PDF file based on its table of contents?

Tags: pdf, table-of-contents

Situation: there is a large pdf file with several hundreds of papers (think of books, technical specifications, etc.). With no access to the original source, how can <del>a table of contents (ToC)</del> an outline be added to a PDF file consisting of text?

There is a similar question to this one, [creating table of contents in a PDF file of scanned book](https://superuser.com/q/872057/47108). That one is however limited to scanned book copies that is not converted with OCR. This question is specifically about PDFs containing text (and perhaps a few figures).

Examples of PDF files:

- http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/asn1-books.html#larmouth
- http://www.acpi.info/DOWNLOADS/ACPIspec10.pdf

These files have a ToC on top of the file which can be clearly identified by the human eye. The sections and chapters within those files can also be found by looking at the preceding heading.

How can I detect the ToC and add an outline to the document? References to documentation of the file format (and such) are also welcome if these can complete the stated task.

(Think of LaTeX-generated PDF files with the `hyperref` package included.)

Comment: But people are free to suggest something if they choose. Read [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5373) for some guidelines.